# Data from a text file is not getting written into an array

Tags: c++, arrays, file-io

I'm trying to write the data from a text file into an array, but when i want to write out values from this array it's full of zero's. The first two lines of the text file are numbers 25 and the rest is a bunch of ones and zeros

```
string line;
    int linenr=3;

    fstream plik;
    plik.open("Maps/default.txt", ios::in);

    if(plik.good() == true)
    {

        while (getline(plik, line))
        {
            for(int x=0;x<25;x++)
            {
                for(int y=0;y<25;y++)
                {
                    map[x][y] = atoi(line.c_str());
                }
            }
            linenr++;
        }
    }
```

i tried to put a getline function in a while loop, so it would be called out until the last line of text, also the getline function would write the text into a "line" string. Next the value from the string would be parsed into an array cell.

Comment: Checking for `plik.good()` is not the same as `plik.is_open()`.

Comment: As currently written, you have a loop which reads one line at a time. And for each line you read, you then overwrite every value in the array with whatever integer value it happens to convert as.

Answer (score 0):

FYI, `std::istream` skips newlines and spaces when looking for integers:

```
for (int row = 0; row < 25; ++row)
{
    for (int column = 0; column < 25; ++column)
    {
        int value = 0;
        plik >> value;
        matrix[row][column] = value;
    }
}
```

The above fragment will read integers into a 25x25 matrix.
The input is assumed to be space separated integers.

**Edit 1:  Line by line**
Let's assume that each line contains a row of data.

```
for (int row = 0; row < 25; ++row)
{
    // Read in a row of numbers.
    std::string row_text;
    std::getline(plik, row_text);

    // Process the row text
    std::istringstream row_stream(row_text);
    int value = 0;
    for (int column = 0; column < 25; ++column)
    {
        row_stream >> value;
        map[row][column] = value;
    }
}
```

**Edit 2: very simple**
Here's very simple, but you'll need to add some validation:

```
int value;
int row = 0;
int column = 0;
while (plik >> value)
{
   matrix[row][column] = value;
   ++column;
   if (column >= 25)
   {
       column = 0;
       ++row;
   }
}
```

There are other methods to read in a space separated input into a matrix.

Comment: I prefer the first process, as it is simpler (it works because newlines are skipped the same as spaces).